# Rstudio Google Analytics API

Tags: r, google-analytics-api

I need help use code to google analytics, using delete, I use the code by https://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/articles/management.html
How do I delete, but keep filters, in this code using

```
dim_filter(dimension="campaign",operator="REGEXP",expressions="welcome")
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter you show in your question is for the reporting API.

For deleting filters applied to your GA account, you need the filter management functions.  Find the filterId you want to delete, then use `ga_filter_delete()` to delete it from your account.

Some documentation is available in the website reference section: https://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/reference/ga_filter_delete.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I just needed to put:

```
dim_filter(dimension="campaign",operator="REGEXP",expressions="welcome", not = TRUE)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).